# Application.dispatchActivityPreCreated - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

I am getting **java.lang.NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityPreCreated** on launch of Activity(**SplashActivity**). It is not happening for everyone but for some users on production. I am not able to reproduce at my end. Sharing full Logs for reference, let me know if any other details are needed.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ActivityName}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityPreCreated(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3454)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2126)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7684)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)

Comment: Did you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: No, I did not find any solution.